# How to nest variables in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I have a simple `Custom` variable called **route** with e.g. this value:

```
/foo/bar,/foo/baz,/foo/baz/foo
```

I'm trying to map these values to some more understandable values, e.g. `Custom` **route_names**:

```
bar,baz,foo
```

Searching on google resulted in people doing nested variables, but whatever I try in Grafana 5.3.4, I can't get it to work. If I do a `Query` variable and use `-- Grafana --` as source, I don't know what to put in the query field. `route.*` didn't do anything, `$route` neither.

What is the correct way of selecting a value from one variable and map it to the other? I.e. What is the query language being used when selecting `-- Grafana --` as datasource?

As a side note, I have two datasources at the moment, my actual data source where I get my graph data from and `-- Grafana --`.

Answer (score 2):

There are correct answers on the first floor. solve "key/value pairs" by `SELECT 'txt1' AS __text, 'value1' AS __value UNION SELECT 'txt2' AS __text, 'value2' AS __value`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `Custom` template variables (unless smth changed in recent Grafana versions). It can be done with variables coming from mysql, postgres and clickhouse datasource queries. See examples in https://community.grafana.com/t/key-value-style-for-custom-template-variable-configuration-and-usage/3109 thread. Can't tell about this feature support in other datasource types.